# Is there a good way to work with this powerpoint file in illustrater

Tags: adobe-illustrator, microsoft-powerpoint

I have quite a complex powerpoint. I made it in powerpoint in the first place, because I knew how to make it like this so far. But now the next part will be easier in illustrator. It has to be handrawings as the last element in the card design. Is there any way to do it with ease?

[image]

I want to insert drawings like this on the cards [image]

Comment: Illustrator can't open Powerpoint files. You might be able to save as PDF and open it in Illustrator, but I would imagine there may be some issues.